# How to go about migrating my firebase web application to a different company like DigitalOcean

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, digital-ocean

i'm working on building my own backend and an API for my project which is currently running on firebase. now the problem is that once the project grows it'll be expensive for me to continue using firebase as there will be a lot of data exchange and traffic and up to million users signing up. how do i migrate from firebase to services like DigitalOcean considering that my authentication data with current users its in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public method in Firebase Authentication to retrieve a list of users. But there is a [process to export the user data](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/zQW-zV6aqQ4), which we're looking to clean up in a future release.

If you're having problems decoding the exported user data, post a question with details or [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.